# Spin UIImageView continuously like 3D

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to spin image  like 3D, not from up/down like clockwise.
I have tried the code below that flip the image, but not rotate continuously.

```
UIImage *picture=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
  flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:picture.CGImage scale:picture.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
    imgV.image=flippedImage;
```

This code rotate image clockwise but I want in 3D style.

```
CABasicAnimation *fullRotation;
fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
fullRotation.duration = 3.5f;
fullRotation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;

[imgV.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say that is not really clear the effect that you want achieve, but if you are meaning something like a flipped page I guess that this snippet can be useful.

```
        CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
        rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 ];
        rotationAnimation.duration = 3;
        rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = NSIntegerMax;
        [logoImage.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

It is something close to a 3d animation, if you want to get more you can host it in another layer and set the `-sublayerTransform` with a specific `CATransform3D` by modifying the m34 value to give the idea of perspective.